# Array not returning correct response with Arrays.binarySearch

Tags: java, arrays

Okay so here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

//@Author: Tyler Cage
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] userID = new String[3];
    String[] password = new String[3];

    for ( int i = 0; i < userID.length; i++){
        System.out.print("User id at index #" + i + " ");
        userID[i] = scnr.next();
        System.out.print("Password at index #" + i + " ");
        password[i] = scnr.next();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter user id: ");
    String userIdInput = scnr.next();

    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    String passwordInput = scnr.next();

    int x = Arrays.binarySearch(userID, userIdInput);
    int y = Arrays.binarySearch(password, passwordInput);

    if(x == y){
        System.out.println("Logged in!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid user id/password combo!");
    }        
}
```

}

I have a weird problem. If I run the program with the array set to 1 then you can log in, but if you run the code as I posted it and try to use the user and pass you set at index 2 it returns a invalid response, as listed below.

```
    run:
User id at index #0 tyler
Password at index #0 111
User id at index #1 jake
Password at index #1 111
User id at index #2 matt
Password at index #2 111
Enter user id: matt
Enter password: 111
Invalid user id/password combo!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Binary search expects the array to be sorted. Unsorted arrays lead to unpredictable results

Comment: `binarySearch` will return the first index for the argument. You're searching for `111` which is at index 0, but `matt` for the username which is at index 2. `2 != 0`.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele 's answer is also correct, but even if the array were sorted, it would still not work.

Comment: what would my go to be for this?

Answer (score 1):

*BinarySearch* algorithm works **only** with **sorted array**:

```
Arrays.sort(userID);
Arrays.sort(password);
int x = Arrays.binarySearch(userID, userIdInput);
int y = Arrays.binarySearch(password, passwordInput);
```